# Redirection of pages in spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a product page which displays all products 
`home.jsp`:

```
<a class="campaign" href="page/dynamic/product1">
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/page/dynamic/{pagename}")
public ModelAndView loadProductPage(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("pagename") String pagename) {
    model.addAttribute("productname",pagename);
    return new ModelAndView("products/"+pagename+"/"+pagename);
}
```

It is getting redirected to the product1 page. Product1 page has a link called features
product1.jsp

```
<li><a href="/page/loadpage/product1/features">Features</a></li>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/page/loadpage/{choosedProduct}/{linkChoosed}")
public ModelAndView loadProductMenuPages(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("linkChoosed") String linkChoosed, @PathVariable("choosedProduct") String choosedProduct) {
    System.out.println("Loading links here");
    System.out.println("cones gere");
    System.out.println("Product Choosed" + choosedProduct);
    System.out.println("Link Choosed" + linkChoosed);
    return new ModelAndView("products/"+choosedProduct+"/"+linkChoosed);
}
```

It is not getting redirected to the "features page", but throws an error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /controller/WEB-INF/views/products/loadpage/loadpage.jsp

What should I need to do to get redirected to features page?

**EDIT:**
Adding `servlet-context.xml` informed in comment:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: You are speaking of *redirect* when code shows *forward*. They are different operations. Please use correct term if controller *forwards* to a view or if you try to redirect say to what URL your want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
In your configuration file please configure below tag

    <bean id="PageRedirect" 
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView">
           <property name="url" value="RedirectPage.jsp" />
    </bean>

And in your controller 
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        return new ModelAndView("PageRedirect");

    }
```